# Recursive search on registry without REG.exe?

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I am writing a BATCH script that I then "compile" with "Quick Batch File Compiler". The compilation is intended to execute the script in Ghost mode (with no windows popup at all).

The problem is that when I compile my file, for I dont know which reason, my BAT is no more able to list all the keys in HKLM\Software (for HKLM\System, it works, etc.).
It is not a right issue, nor a "space" or something like that. It seems to be an ErrorLevel issue specifically in this situation (the same .BAT file witout compilation is working correctly).

So I would like to be able to recursively search for specific registry values (that are in a TXT file) on the whole registry; without using REG.exe

Do you have an idea on how can I do that in a .BAT ?

Here is the very basic code that let me reproduce the issue with QBFC

```
    reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion
REM reg query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\iaStorF"

echo The errorlevel is : %ERRORLEVEL% for this key
If %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (
echo %date%;%time%;%computername%;%%u >> %computername%_reg.csv
)
)

@pause
```

So this code works great from a .BAT file but doesnt work when it has been compiled with QFBC.

From the EXE version, I have an ErrorLevel to 1, because the key is not found. From the BAT version, the key is correctly found (it is the exact same code).

Quick Batch File COmpiler can be downloaded here : http://www.abyssmedia.com/quickbfc/

Many thanks !

Comment: There is not a native batch method to search the registry. Can you show us your code? It might help us find the issue.

Comment: You could add a PowerShell command to your batch script -- something like `powershell "gci -path registry::HKLM\Software | %{ $_.Name }"`  (Of course, in a batch script you might need to double-pump the `%%` in that command to specify a literal `%` and not a variable identifier.)

Comment: I have edited my post to add the code tested. QBFC is this app : http://www.abyssmedia.com/quickbfc/

Comment: What exactly does "not working" mean? The file `'%computername%_reg.csv` doesn't get created? Or it's empty? Something else?

Comment: Sorry you're right ! Well, If I execute the EXE, some subkeys of HKLM\Software are not listed and so the search is not relevant. And if I launch the scan directlry from the BAT, I can list everything in HKLM\Software and so I can find one of the Subkey that I know is present.

Comment: When you run the compiled version you get _some_ of the registry keys returned, but not all that you're expecting?

Comment: Yes aphoria, that's right. And I think I found the issue. QFBC is using the REG.EXE located in SYSWOW64 folder and this one only retrieves partial results (even in a CMD ! )  Now I am trying to enforce the script to use the reg.exe located in System32 folder (but even by defining the path like this, it doesnt work : %windir%\system32\reg.exe query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AcctCfg"

Comment: What the `%%u` stands for? If your code snippet is a part of an outer `for` loop, then you need [EnableDelayedExpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) and use `if !errorlevel! EQU 0` or `if not errorlevel 1` instead of `if %errorlevel% EQU 0`